# Android Retrofit troubles

Tags: java, android, retrofit

So I am trying to make use of retrofit to pull information from wikipedia. 
These are the classes with the relevant retrofit code:

https://github.com/smholsen/whatIsThisThing/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/simon/whatisthisthing/RetrofitBuilder.java

https://github.com/smholsen/whatIsThisThing/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/simon/whatisthisthing/WikiInfo.java

https://github.com/smholsen/whatIsThisThing/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/simon/whatisthisthing/WikiService.java

Retrofit doesnt throw any exceptions, but the

`Log.i("RetrofitResponse", mResponse.toString());`

in the onResponse callback method shows that the returned body just contains null...

Does any of you see any obvious mistakes I've done?

Is this:

```
interface WikiService {

    @GET("?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=")
    Call<WikiInfo> search(@Query("titles") String search);
}
```

The correct way of denoting this uri? : https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=pizza&format=json

How does retrofit know how to map the json fields to my WikiInfo object fields? I gave the fields in the class the same names as the keys in the json response.

I will be very grateful for any response!

Thanks alot in advance.

Best regards

Comment: *How does retrofit know how to map the json fields to my WikiInfo object fields* -- It delegates that to Gson. And you should annotate you java object class accordingly

Comment: you are returning mResponse way before it has any chance of being populated. You need to understand that the call is asynchronous, which is the whole point of having a callback

Comment: Right! Nice catch :)  I understand. But the current problem is that the received response.body() doesnt contain what I expected (see comments in accepted answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a problem about your pojos. Here's an example pojos to get data from wikipedia api with retrofit.

**Edit: Main Wrapper class called Result**

```
public class Result {
    @SerializedName("batchcomplete")
    private String result;
    @SerializedName("query")
    private Query query;
}
```

Query Class:

```
public class Query {
    @SerializedName("pages")
    private Map<String, Page> pages;

    public Map<String, Page> getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public void setPages(Map<String, Page> pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }
}
```

And Page

```
public class Page {
    @SerializedName("pageid")
    private long id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("extract")
    private String content;
}
```

And here's your Services interface:

```
interface WikiService {
    @GET("?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=")
    Call<Result> search(@Query("titles") String search);
}
```

Basically you need a **wrapper class**. Wikipedia's json response's labels which you need to match with your `Page` pojo can be changed. And also number can be changed. So you need to match with a `Map` to get a successful response with `Retrofit`.

Here's my example GitHub project with you can see an example implementation with wikipedia api and retrofit.

https://github.com/savepopulation/wikilight

Comment: Hope it's okay - I used your repo in my answer. Also, I don't think OP is needing the RealmObjects

Comment: yes in your case realm objects is unnecessary. you can use my repo how ever you want.

Comment: @cricket_007 I still cringe whenever I see `realm.copyFromRealm()` in the local data source but that's ok

Comment: you can just copy pojos which named with Query and Page and remove unnecessary fields which is used for realm. and i'll be glad if you accept my answer.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Not sure what you are referring to. I'm not "using the repo", just referenced in my answer.

Comment: Hey! I am super thankful for your answer! I am trying to figure things out right now :D I am struggling a bit with understanding how  @SerializedName works.

Comment: @SimonOlsen https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#json-field-naming-support

Comment: When retrofit matches wikipedia response json's objects with you pojos, it use SerializedName annotation.

Comment: So I tried to use your query and pages pojos, and I actually get a Query object (!) Which is progress, but when trying to print out the pages.toString from that Query object I get a nullPointer. So I guess that means that either the returned json doesnt contain a field "pages" (so maybe something is wrong with my URI?) Or there is something else I am still doing wrong...
Upon debugging I found this; Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php/?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=pizza}
So the uri looks right.

Comment: if i'm not wrong some queries may not have pages. you can search "google" and check again. google has pages.

Comment: But the response.body() returns with the rawResponse I wrote in the previous comment, and clicking that link shows that it actually should contain a page.. (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php/?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=pizza)

Comment: oh i'm sorry i forget to add main wrapper pojo which called result. i edited my answer. check it out please

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i did not understand what you mean "I still cringe whenever I see realm.copyFromRealm() in the local data source" is my realm implementation in repo wrong?

Answer (score 2):

So, here's the JSON you get back.

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "normalized": [{
            "from": "pizza",
            "to": "Pizza"
        }],
        "pages": {
            "24768": {
                "pageid": 24768,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Pizza",
                "extract": "Pizza is a yeasted flatbread generally topped with tomato sauce and cheese and baked in an oven. It is commonly topped with a selection of meats, vegetables and condiments. The term was first recorded in the 10th century, in a Latin manuscript from Gaeta in Central Italy. The modern pizza was invented in Naples, Italy, and the dish and its variants have since become popular and common in many areas of the world.\nIn 2009, upon Italy's request, Neapolitan pizza was safeguarded in the European Union as a Traditional Speciality Guaranteed dish. The Associazione Verace Pizza Napoletana (the True Neapolitan Pizza Association) is a non-profit organization founded in 1984 with headquarters in Naples. It promotes and protects the \"true Neapolitan pizza\".\nPizza is sold fresh or frozen, either whole or in portions, and is a common fast food item in Europe and North America. Various types of ovens are used to cook them and many varieties exist. Several similar dishes are prepared from ingredients commonly used in pizza preparation, such as calzone and stromboli."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's your (stripped-down) Java class.

```
public class WikiInfo {
    private String name;
    private String extract;
}
```

Retrofit delegates the JSON handling to Gson, which you set here.

```
private Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

It is having issues trying to know what you want out of that JSON, and it can't simply know you wanted `response["query"]["pages"]`, then page id `#24768`, and `"title"` and `"extract"` from that.

---

So, the solution is either

1. Don't reinvent the wheel. Find a reasonable Java API for Wikipedia or see if an existing Retrofit Wikipedia sample exists. (See [WikiLight](https://github.com/savepopulation/wikilight), for example)
2. Continue on with what you have, but do some research into how to properly implement your `WikiInfo` classes. See the Gson documentation to get started with that, but an object with a `Map<String, Page> page` would be a good start. Then `Page.java` contains `private String title, extract;`

Comment: Thanks for an awesome reply!
What kind of object would "query" be here? Would it be an arraylist containing two arraylists? (normalized and pages) ? 
Do you have any tips on where I can find some information on how to properly implement the WikiInfo class? :)

Comment: I think the other answer has you covered on that.